# Background image shows when set to cover, but not when set to contain?

Tags: html, css

I am building a react app, and I am writing responsive sass code to make my site look nice. I am trying to make my background image scale, and I am trying to use the background-size: contain; property to do so.

I'm running into a bug I can't fix though... When the background size is set to "cover", the image shows no problem. When I change that property to "contain", the image doesn't show anymore. The image is being loaded according to the console, and I can see it in the inspector as a style on the body where I have it attached. What gives? Why won't the image show? Here's the relevant css.

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: center / contain no-repeat url("../img/boulder.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Removing `position: absolute` seems to solve it, I'm not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure with that syntax you are using in the background property but this seems to accomplish the desired result: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-nobel-tmvno?file=/src/styles.css:67-138

```
  background-position: contain;
  background: no-repeat center url("../img/boulder.jpg");
```

Comment: In his example he is styling `body`, not `.App` if you change the selector in the sandbox you provided the problem persists

Comment: Actually, this did work, the problem doesn't persist after implementing it... And the syntax is the background shorthand. I actually looked up how to write it shorthand, and found it written like that on some page of StackOverflow...

Comment: Weird, it's still not working for me, I've probably made a silly mistake

Comment: Sorry I did the work then forgot to save. Basically, I just broke it away from the shorthand and it seems to resolve the issue. I am honestly unsure why. Perhaps the shorthand is formatted incorrectly, but ole tried and true worked